# How to the replace node names with new name and keep the attributes using C# and Linq to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I need to change

```
<Test Language="English" Id="0" />
```

to

```
<Exam Language="English" Id="0" />
```

How to the replace node names with new name and keep the attributes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Name` property

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
var nodes=xdoc.Descendants("Test").ToList();//Get all "Test" node 
nodes.ForEach(d => d.Name = "Exam "); // Set name to 'Exam'
xdoc.Save("output.xml");
```